# PHP file redirection 404 error

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have read the other posts regarding this but it was a different problem.

```
<form action="mk.php" method="get">
```

This form will call mk.php when the user submits the form. I have tried putting the mk.php file in the home directory, the wp-admin directory but the form can't find it. I get a 404 error. In the URL bar, it shows
http://bdeas.com/marketplace/mk.php?username=test123&link=test123&submit=Send
instead of
http://bdeas.com/mk.php?username=test123&link=test123&submit=Send

Where am I supposed to place the mk.php file so that my page can find it?

Also, can I make it so that wordpress searches for the file in the home directory instead of /marketplace?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in a theme you need to place the file in the theme directory, and then set the action like this...

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mk.php" method="get">
```

If you are creating a form within a post or page, place the file in the home directory and set the action like this...

```
<form action="/mk.php" method="get">
```

The leading slash will tell the form to look in the home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the location of

```
<form action="mk.php" method="get">
```

?

because if you have that code in the main folder and mk.php is in the /marketplace/ folder, then it should be

```
<form action="marketplace/mk.php" method="get">
```